# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Всем привет! Не могу импортировать модуль pdftableextract.

Операционная система: Windows 7, 64 bit
Python версия 3.6.1, Anaconda custom, 64 bit

Хочу импортировать пакет который установил таким образом:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ashima/pdf-table-extract.
```

Вот код в скрипте:

```
import pandas as pd
import pdftableextract as pdf

pages = ["1"]
path = r'C:\Users\a.iganov\PycharmProjects\pdfReading\files\UG-0225-KOC DDR wc-Report Number  52-(04-29-2014) - 2.PDF'
cells = [pdf.process_page(path, p) for p in pages]

cells = [item for sublist in cells for item in sublist ]

li = pdf.table_to_list(cells, pages)[1]

this table only!)

data = pd.DataFrame(li[2:-1], columns=li[1], index=[l[0] for l in li[2:-1]])
print (data)
```

Ругается на файл __init__.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a.iganov/PycharmProjects/pdfReading/pdfTableExtractExample.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pdftableextract as pdf
  File "C:\Users\a.iganov\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdftableextract\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core import process_page, output, table_to_list
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

Зашел в указанную директорию файлы на месте. 
Зашел внутрь файла__init__.py там всего 2 строчки:

```
# Example package with a console entry point
from core import process_page, output, table_to_list
```

По сабжу, есть ли еще какие нибудь готовые модули для парсинга таблиц с конкретной структурой из pdf формата в JSON, Excel, xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по строкам с импортами, которые приведены в сообщении об ошибке, вы используете пакет для Python 2.

В Python 3 относительный импорт без точки не работает и правильный код выглядел бы следующим образом:

```
from .core import process_page, output, table_to_list
     ^
```

Если посмотреть код, то можно [увидеть, что он действительно написан на Python 2](https://github.com/ashima/pdf-table-extract/blob/7a04fc5a99b74aebecda208bf9680bb2cad2cc72/src/pdftableextract/pnm.py#L31):

```
if m != 255 :
    print "Just want 8 bit pgms for now!"
```

Можете попробовать использовать код из [Pull Request](https://github.com/ashima/pdf-table-extract/pull/23) или найти другую библиотеку

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ, парился еще 2-3 часа с пулл реквестом, но нужных результатов этот пакет мне не дал. Вы случайно не знаете другие пакеты для парсинга структурированных таблиц в pdf формате? Вот такая ситуация, у меня около 40-50 тысяч 1 страничных pdf файлов, в них таблицы одинаковой структуры. Надо из этих таблиц спарсить данные в JSON или xml, ну или в листы и словари что бы легче было работать, делать математические операций.

Comment: Нет, опыта в использовании библиотек на Python, которые могут помочь с этой проблемой, у меня нет, надо искать...

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка же не в модуле `pdftableextract`.

В ошибке явно написано что вы пытаетесь импортировать какой то модуль `core`, уберите импорт этого модуля, или покажите полный код где вы его используете.

Comment: это внутренний import/вызов из `pdftableextract` модуля - в ответе @TimofeyBondarev дан достаточно подробный анализ